# Confirmação na planilha com Python e Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Estou tentando fazer uma lista de presença com o python, onde o convidado chega, e eu digito o RG dele para confirmar presença em uma planilha do Excel. Porem não estou conseguindo adicionar um ( OK )  nessa planilha,

O Código que eu fiz foi esse.

```
import pandas as pd

convidados_df = pd.read_excel(f'Cadastro.xlsx')
convidados = convidados_df['NomeCompleto']
identificacao = convidados_df['RG']


dicionario = dict(zip(convidados, identificacao))
rg = 2029300091
PrimeiroDia = []


for chave, valor in dicionario.items():
    if rg == valor:
        PrimeiroDia.append('Confirmado')

print(PrimeiroDia)
```

assim o resultado sai bacana no terminal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu queria mesmo era adicionar um OK na planilha do Excel

Answer (score 0):

```python
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

convidados_df = pd.read_excel('Cadastro.xlsx')

rg_input = input('Digite o rg a ser conferido')

convidados_df['Confirmação'] = np.where(convidados_df['RG'] ==rg_input, 'ok', 'no')

convidados_df

convidados_df.to_excel('Cadastro.xlsx')
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.
Porém a saída não esta acontecendo, quando estou digitando o ( RG ) ele não esta dando um ( ok ) para confirmar.  Vou adicionar uma nova resposta com uma imagem para você vê como esta ficando, eu gostaria que colocasse um OK cada vez que eu digitar o rg da pessoa. no primeiro dia, segundo dia e terceiro dia. 
Se ja tivesse um ok no primeiro dia ele colocasse no segundo, se ja tivesse no segundo ele colocasse no terceiro dia e etc.